# as.POSIXct() can't convert a particular time

Tags: r, date, posixct

I use as.POSIXct() to convert character to time stamp. It works well on my data frame except one entry:

```
as.POSIXct("03/29/2015-02:49:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
```

This returns NA. I tried it with strptime() as follows:

```
strptime("03/29/2015-02:49:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
```

It works but return a date of format POSIXlt. I used as.POSIXct() to transform this result but then it still returns NA.

Anyone has an idea how comes it behaves like this?

Comment: It works for me, yielding `2015-03-29 02:49:13 EET`. Maybe you have some issue with time zones or locale?

Comment: Works fine for me as well: as.POSIXct("03/29/2015-02:49:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-03-29 02:49:13 EDT"

Comment: transition to daylight saving time (DST) ... https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2015.html